# Python call class function without reffering class name

Tags: python, c++, class

The code bellow in c++ is working, Its possible to make this works with python without using `Users().Users(23, "bell")` but like c++ `Users(23, "bell")` see my code bellow

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Users
{
public:
    int age;
    string name;

public:
    Users()
    {
        // init default 
        age = 90;
        name = "john";

    }

    Users(int iage, string iname)
    {
        age = iage;
        name = iname;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Users User;
    User.age = 2;
    User.name = "l";

    Users(23, "bell");
    return 0;
}
```

''

```
class Users:
    age = None
    name = None 

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 90
        self.name = "john"

    def Users(age, name):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

User = Users()
User.age = 2
User.name = "l"
```

Comment: .... that's what the `__init__` function's there for. `__init__` is python's constructor. just add the arguments there and remove your  `User` method, it has no special meaning in Python.

Comment: Have you read the basic tutorial? Your actual question is unclear but I'm pretty sure you're trying to add arguments to `__init__`.

Comment: no i dont want to add arg to __init__

Comment: Yes you do. Function (or constructor) overloading is done with default arguments in python.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question. Solutions don't belong in the question, they should be posted as answers.

Comment: @chepner What was wrong with that dupe?

Comment: Nothing in particular, but the OP had enough misconceptions that I think he needed a custom answer.

Comment: Related/dupe: [What is a clean, pythonic way to have multiple constructors in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/682504)

Comment: (I'm willing to be flagged for my probable abuse of dup-hammer reopening powers :))

Comment: @chepner If you think there's value in reopening the question, fine - but I honestly don't see how your answer is an improvement over the answer in the dupe. Did you address any of those misconceptions?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I fixed the class name and variable name conventions, got rid of the class attributes and unnecessary methods, and provided several examples of how to use the single constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use default arguments to provide values when you don't want to pass a default value explicitly.

```
class User:  # singular noun
    def __init__(self, age=90, name="john"):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

user1 = User()            # user.age == 90, user.name == "john"
user2 = User(2, "l")      # user.age == 2, user.name == "l"
user3 = User(40)          # user.age == 40, user.name == "john"
user4 = User(name="bob")  # user.age == 90, user.name == "john"
```

Since the unspecified arguments are replaced by defaults in strict left-to-right order, the last example shows the use of a keyword argument to set the name explicitly while using the default age.